# Opposite of e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote some javascript code that prevents scrolling on focus. How do I disable it after focus is lost?

Focus

```
e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
```

Focus out

```
e.preventDefault = false;
e.stopPropagatio = false;
```

Comment: Would it be worth trying to unbind the event listener? Or put the methods behind a boolean flag?

Comment: You can't undo them. Just stop calling them.

Comment: @evolutionxbox that fixed it :). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed by unbinding the event.

Focus

```
    $('.form-control').focus(function() {  
            $('#element').on('scroll touchmove mousewheel', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
        })
});
```

Focus out

```
$('.form-control').focusout(function() {
        $('#element').unbind();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't undo `preventDefault` nor `stopPropagation`.

Just stop calling them, e.g.

```
var stopScroll = true;
element.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  if (stopScroll) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
// ...
stopScroll = false;
```

```
function listener() {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
}
element.addEventListener('scroll', listener);
// ...
element.removeEventListener('scroll', listener);
```